# UPDATE certain row in SELECTED items with Certain id

Tags: php, mysql, database

I need to Select a column with name song_number where id = 2 and then update the second row  from the selected rows with 7 for example

what i think that the query i need is something like this but i can't get it work

```
UPDATE `song` SET `song_number`= 7 WHERE (SELECT `song_number` FROM `song` WHERE `id` = 2 LIMIT 1,1)
```

any help will be appreciated

edit: i think the problem is mainly in the database structure i made however i found a solution to what i need by making stored procedure http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html
so that i can save the selected items in a procedure and then update it

Comment: Wow, sounds like awful design. If you have to navigate records by record occurrence rather than via column values - you've done something wrong.

Comment: The "second" row? In what order? Rows do not have a predefined order.

Comment: what about having them ordered in an ascending order i don't think that this is the problem

Comment: Ascending order of what? id? song_number? If you posted a few rows with sample data and the table's definition (what is the Primary Key for example?) would be better for others to understand this twisted logic.

Comment: well i'm a beginner in mysql who needs some help to do so and for sure i have some errors in what i'm doing, anyway the items are automatically added from input fields in a form with php so what i think of is that they will have the order that i need by default

Comment: Items (rows) do NOT have a default order. Nor you should assume they have. They sometimes (or often) are retrieved in the order they were stored in the table. Or in the order of the Primary Key. Or in some arbitrary order the MySQL engine chooses. There is no guarantee on that and you should not count on any default order. You should use `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, and sorry if my question wasn't correct

Comment: Remember that you can edit your questions, adding more info as needed or asked by commentators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to identify which row you want to update. Identification means using a `UNIQUE` key or the `PRIMARY` key of the table.

The limitation of MySQL on `UPDATE` can be lifted by moving the condition from the `WHERE` to a `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE 
      song AS s
  JOIN
      ( SELECT  PK                --- the Primary Key of the tba;e 
        FROM song 
        WHERE id = 2 
        ORDER BY ---whatever
        LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
      ) AS u
    ON u.PK = s.PK
SET s.song_number= 7
```

---

If the `PRIMARY KEY` is `id`, then the above is useless of course. You are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it is possible with one query and yet I see no reason in doing it in one query.
Why can't you just select and then update?

Comment: I have tried to do so but i failed here is what i have tried
Select song_number From song WHERE id = 2 LIMIT 1,1;
Update song SET song_number = 7;

the output is that the whole column song_number will have the value of 7

So i think i have to make it in one single query i think

Comment: you have to set up WHERE clause for update, dude. What are you doing in general? It seems you don't understand what are you doing at all

Answer (score 0):

I think should be like this:

```
UPDATE `song` SET `song_number`= 7 WHERE `song_number` = (SELECT `song_number` FROM `song` WHERE `id` = 2 LIMIT 1,1);
```

Comment: i tried it and here is the error that appears: You can't specify target table 'song' for update in FROM clause